Unit Testing in TCL
In tcl, I have a library that I want to unit test, so every proc in the library should be tested separately. So when I have a proc proc foo that itself call another library proc proc bar (among doing other things), the testing should not include an actual call of proc bar. Instead, a placeholder proc should be called, that just tells the test procedure that proc bar would have been called and with which parameters.
After reading on the internet, I tried to rename the procs. My library files look like this:
proc foo {} {
    # something
    bar argument
    # something
    return 1
}

proc bar {argument} {
    # something that should not be executed while testing foo
}

The .test file looks like this:
test test_foo {} -body {
    proc ::bar_newDefinition {} {
    }
    rename bar ::bar_originalDefinition
    rename ::bar_newDefinition bar
    set result [foo]
    rename bar ::bar_newDefinition
    rename ::bar_originalDefinition bar
    set result 
} -result 1

This procedure seems to be what others recommend, but it doesn't seem to work the way I implemented it. executing the test test_foo will still lead to the original proc bar being executed. Am I doing something wrong in the code?

My only thought is that there is a namespace issue? Are you sure that bar refers to the same bar that is invoked by foo?

Unfortunately, we need more details. Tcl doesn't normally do early binding of command implementations... but can do with namespace import.

So when inside the test itself I call bar, then very proc that I intend to call is activated. So from this I concluded that also the renaming will refer to this very function, but maybe I'm wrong?
When it comes to namespace import, do you mean I should import the namespace of the library, or something else?
